# Azure AD B2C: Microsoft Graph API Error - Property 'mobile' does not exist as a declared property or extension property

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to search user using Microsoft Graph API and it works for few attribute like filter=givenName
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=givenName eq 'testuser'&$select=surname

I want to search user with mobile number, tried
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mobile eq '+******'&$select=surname

**It gives me an error:**

"code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
"message": "Property 'mobile' does not exist as a declared property or extension property."

Comment: Currently, it is working in beta for [Azure Ad](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39650161-filter-on-mobilephone-in-user-information) but there is an issue in B2C. Please refer to this [Github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9856)  and update you accordingly

Comment: I tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=surname,mobilePhone&$filter=mobilePhone eq '123456'&$count=true` and it worked.

Comment: @PamelaPeng did that work for B2C?

Comment: @ThomHubers The $count and $search parameters are currently not available in Azure AD B2C tenants, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can use the below query for AAD to filter the users by using `ConsistencyLevel:eventual`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,displayName,mobilePhone&$filter=startswith(mobilePhone,'***')&$count=true
ConsistencyLevel:eventual
```

[image]

For Azure ADb2c users filter query with counts and Consistency=eventual is actually not supported for B2C tenants. For more information please refer to [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9856)